# Vue: how to pass props when dynamically creating a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a component dynamically (after a button click), using this [commonly followed tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/). The basic code is:

```js
import Building_Info from './Info_Zone/Building'
var Building_Info_Class = Vue.extend(Building_Info)
var building_info_instance = new Building_Info_Class()
console.log(building_info_instance)
bulding_info_instance.$mount()
place_to_add_component.$el.appendChild(bulding_info_instance.$el)
```

However, my Building_Info component requires a prop. How can I pass it in? Alternative ways to dynamically creare components are welcome, though *ideally* they'd support Single File Components.

*Note: there are several SO questions about dynamic props, but none I see that speak to this question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor returned from `Vue.extend` (i.e., `Building_Info_Class`) can receive an initialization object, containing the [`propsData` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#propsData) with initial prop values:

```js
var building_info_instance = new Building_Info_Class({
  propsData: {
    propA: '123',
    propB: true,
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-instantiate-component-with-props?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Thank you, that works!